# Mac Sandbox & file-ioctl

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I'm currently sandboxing a program that connects to the NeuroSky MindWave headset; essentially a brainwave reading device that connects via a USB dongle and uses Blutooth in between.

The device is accessible via the /dev/tty.MindWave socket.

I have added a temporary entitlement for read right access to the file:

```
   <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>/dev/tty.MindWave</string>
    </array>
```

and that gets rid of the sandboxd error messages for the file, but now brings up the following error:

```
deny file-ioctl /dev/tty.MindWave
```

There does not appear to be a matching temporary entitlement.. meaning that I'll have to remove support for the device from the Mac App Store version soon.

Before doing that, however, I thought I'd send out an SOS and see whether anybody on this group has a solution..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

This doc might help:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EnablingAppSandbox/EnablingAppSandbox.html

and it looks like the entitlement key you need is:

```
com.apple.security.device.usb
```

I feel your pain: I'm wrestling with Login Items in Sandbox and have only just got to the end of a long tunnel!

Hope it helps and that device sounds amazing - had heard of such things but didn't realise they were publicly available!!

Todd

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm fairly certain that I tried the com.apple.security.device.usb entitlement, but that it didn't work.

The cocoa plug-in that Neurosky have you bundle with your app does not actually talk to the device directly, but to the a daemon that runs as a separate process. I'll try it again just in case, as I know precious little about how their device driver works :-)

Comment: Ahh, a daemon. That could be problematic in sandbox. Make sure it's sandboxed and code-signed as well. It may need to be put in a specific location too. Have a look at http://www.delitestudio.com/2011/10/25/start-dockless-apps-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled/ it might be of use here....